# Fitnesse don't recognize SequenceFixture tables

Tags: fitnesse

I tried to run the example from the fitnesse web

```
package info.fitnesse.fixturegallery;
import java.util.Arrays;
import fitlibrary.SequenceFixture;

public class SequenceFixtureTest extends SequenceFixture{
    public String letters;
    public void fill(int count,char c){
        char[] arr=new char[count];
        Arrays.fill(arr,c);
        letters=new String(arr);
    }
    public void setList(char[] array){
        letters=new String(array);
    }
    public char charAt(int position){
        return letters.charAt(position);
    }
}
```

But when i try to run the example table

```
!|SequenceFixtureTest|
|fill|10|x|
|check|char at|4|x|
|set list|A,B,C,D|
|check|char at|2|C|
```

I get the error

```
SequenceFixtureTest: Bad table! Table has 3 header columns, but row 2 only has 2 columns.
```

I imported the lib of SequenceFixture. It seems that it tries to recognize the table like a ColumnFixture and that is what i get the error of Bad Table, but i don't want a ColumnFixture.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using !define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}

Comment: No, i'm using slim, that's the reason? but that way i cannot do imports, right?

Comment: SequenceFixture is not supported by Slim.  I believe Fit has an ImportFixture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SequenceFixture` is not supported by Slim.  You need to use  `!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}`